# Maven verify on a sub-module fails with 'dependencies.dependency.version' for some.artefact:jar is missing

Tags: maven, svn, continuous-integration

In a Jenkins CI job, a single module of a multi-module Maven project is checked out from svn and the following Maven goals are specified:

```
clean verify pmd:pmd
```

The build fails with the error message

> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
> encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR]
> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jdom:jdom2:jar is missing. @
> line 162, column 21

The missing version is only specified in the main (master) pom, which was not checked out.

To fix this I can check out the whole multi-module project, but are there other options which limit the check-out to only the required files - the master pom.xml and the module?

Additional information: the build worked well in the past, with many other dependency versions which were not specified in the module. All these artefacts were already in the local .m2 repository. Now with a new dependency this error occurs. I guess that it has something to do how Maven handles version matching when artefacts are already installed.

Comment: If you have a multi module you have to run the multi module not a single module... what will not work... if it's not checked that this will not work anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins offers to perform more than one check-out operation for a Maven build job. In the first one I specifiy the path to main (master) project, and set repository depth to "files". The second contains the module to-be-verified.

Comment: Checkout the whole project is easier...

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree, but there are many modules with frequent commits, and I have to figure out how to trigger a build only for selected changes. Otherwise the build will run every few minutes, and it is quite resource consuming.